# Eclipse edu.stanford.nlp Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, stanford-nlp

Been working on this error since 2 days and cant find a solution: I'm trying to run edu.stanford.nlp. in my java project in Eclipse.
Done so far:
Installed maven, extracted the latest stanfordnlp-master .ZIP file, drag and dropped the files directly into my "angni" project (replaced the original src folder), ran pom.xml as maven build (successful), tried to a class with a main function it it, but always when running one of the classes, it gives me the following Error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Elias.Dictionary

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Elias.Dictionary
```

For further review to test it on your machines: my .ZIP file of my eclipse project (attention, >200MB) is too big to upload it to github, so I uploaded it to [google drive:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nx_Hy7e7IOowfvhyYi-k_g0N14gwkH8Z/view?usp=share_link) (will keep it there for future visits of this post).

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is "Elias.Dictionary" ? Is that one of your classes?  (Hint: nobody is going to download 200MB of stuff from your Google Drive.  Figure out a better way to provide us with the relevant information.  It sounds like this really just a simple classpath problem and that doesn't need 200MB to demonstrate.)

Comment: You replaced the original "src" folder, but haven't established that that folder matters to Eclipse. Append your .classpath file. And if it came as a Maven project, have you tried importing it as Maven project, with the wizard?